# How to link a cell's value from excel to an image with Python code?

Tags: python, machine-learning, label

I have an Excel file with the following format:

| Name | Rating | Contrast |
| --- | --- | --- |
| picture_1 | 4 | 5 |
| picture_2 | 3 | 6 |

My problem is that I want to link the rating '4' of the picture_1 with the actual picture (a .jpeg file). How can I do that using python?

I appreciate any help and answers as I'm a beginner in this field. Many thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.